# mix the result of 2 queries in one table?

Tags: sql, merge, ms-access-2007

I am new to SQL, can i mix the result of two queries in one table with different attributes ?

Below 3 tables of my database and the result i want to get. Is this possible ?

client

```
|id|name|adress|
----------------
|1 |a   |x     |
|2 |b   |y     |
```

order

```
|id|client.id|product|date     |
--------------------------------
|1 |1        |px     |2018-01-1|
|2 |1        |py     |2018-05-1|
|3 |2        |px     |2018-06-1|
```

pay

```
|id|client.id|amount|date     |
-------------------------------
|1 |1        |1000  |2018-03-1|
|2 |2        |500   |2018-09-1|
```

Output

```
|name |order.id |product |pay.id |amount |date     |
----------------------------------------------------
|a    |1        |px      |-      |-      |2018-01-1|
|a    |-        |-       |1      |1000   |2018-03-1|
|a    |2        |py      |-      |-      |2018-05-1|
|b    |3        |px      |-      |-      |2018-06-1|
|b    |-        |-       |2      |500    |2018-09-1|
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.  Is it MySQL or MS Access?

Comment: you are looking for joins. But you need to tell us what database you are using

Comment: it is ms access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** for Access. 
Use `UNION` for 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT client.name, order.id AS orderid, order.product AS product, 
    "-" AS payid, "-" AS amount, order.date AS [date]
  FROM client INNER JOIN [order] ON client.id = order.clientid
  UNION
  SELECT client.name, "-" AS orderid, "-" AS product, 
    pay.id AS payid, pay.amount AS amount, pay.date AS [date]
  FROM client INNER JOIN [pay] ON client.id = pay.clientid
  )
ORDER BY name, date
```

the result is:

```
name    orderid product payid   amount  date
a         1       px      -       -     2018-01-1
a         -       -       1      1000   2018-03-1
a         2       py      -       -     2018-05-1
b         3       px      -       -     2018-06-1
b         -       -       2      500    2018-09-1
```